# Как совместить entry с выпадающим списком? Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать Entry при вводе в которое выпадало бы меню с предлагаемыми вариантами. (Как это сделано в поисковиках, например, при вводе "Как ..." предлагается куча вариантов типа "Как научиться пользоваться гуглом" и пр.)
Спасибо.

Comment: Интересует аналогичный вопрос, вы случаем не нашли ответа?

Comment: Автоматически выпадающие варианты реализовать не удалось, но сделал так: при вводе в ttk.Combobox, он автоматически заполняется возможным вариантом. Например, начинаю вводить "Как " и сразу заполняется "как научиться пользоваться гуглом", но если я продолжаю ввод и набираю "Как ск" то уже автоматически забивается, ну, скажем, "Как скачать с youtube". Если интересует код, могу скинуть